# How to Add A Picker when selecting multiple textfield , I already One TextField working?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitextfield, uipickerview

I Already have three TextField Outlet connected on my Nib File

```
IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFieldd;
IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFields;
```

Now I am Trying To Add a Picker to Pop Out when you select myTextFieldd and myTextFields, notice that myTextField Works Great. I Also am Trying to Use the Same Picker to POP Up for the Three TextFields.

Code:
     #import "PickrAppViewController.h"

```
@implementation PickrAppViewController

@synthesize categoryArray,selectedCategory;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Jack",@"Jone",nil];

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

if(textField == myTextField)
{
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    if([myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    myTextField.text = [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }   
    NSInteger pickerRow;
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.categoryArray count]; i++){
        NSString *string = [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if([string isEqualToString:myTextField.text]){
            pickerRow = i;
            break;  //Once we have it break out of the loop
        }
    }
    [picker selectRow:pickerRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];

    pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, pickrView.frame.size.width,    pickrView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.50];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, pickrView.frame.size.width, pickrView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:pickrView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    return NO;


}

if([pickrView superview]){
    [self animationForPickrDown];
}
return YES;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if([pickrView superview]){
[self animationForPickrDown];
}
 }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark PickrView datasource methods

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
self.selectedCategory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[categoryArray    objectAtIndex:row]];
myTextField.text = self.selectedCategory;
[self animationForPickrDown];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [self.categoryArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];
}


- (void) animationForPickrDown
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, pickrView.frame.size.width,  pickrView.frame.size.height);
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.50];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stopAnimation)];
pickrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, pickrView.frame.size.width, pickrView.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];  
}

- (void) stopAnimation
{
if([pickrView superview]){
    [pickrView removeFromSuperview];
}
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[myTextField release];
[pickrView release];
[selectedCategory release];
}

@end
```

Thank You

Comment: If its showing for one and not showing for other two, you have to just comment this condition if(textField == myTextField).

Comment: i already did that , for myTextField , but what about the other two textField (myTextFieldd, and myTextFields) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set delegate for other textfields and then remove condition  if(textField == myTextField).

and

**remove**

```
if([pickrView superview]){
    [self animationForPickrDown];
}

    return YES;
```